# Why console.log goes infinite in async_hooks nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why console.log which is present inside init, before, after, destroy functions in async_hooks leads to infinite maximum call stack exceed problem?

Why does the below code goes infinite,

```
let asycn_hooks = require('async_hooks');

async_hooks.createHook({
  init(asyncId, type, triggerAsyncId) {
    console.log(asyncId);
  },
  before(asyncId) {
    console.log(asyncId);
  },
  after(asyncId) {
    console.log(asyncId);
  },
  destroy(asyncId) {
    console.log(asyncId);
  },
}).enable();
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('>>>', async_hooks.executionAsyncId());
}, 10);
```

but the below code doesn't

```
let async_hooks = require('async_hooks');
let fs = require('fs');

async_hooks.createHook({
  init(asyncId, type, triggerAsyncId) {
    fs.writeFileSync(1,`init ${asyncId} \n`);
  },
  before(asyncId) {
    fs.writeFileSync(1,`before ${asyncId} \n`);
  },
  after(asyncId) {
    fs.writeFileSync(1,`after ${asyncId} \n`);
  },
  destroy(asyncId) {
    fs.writeFileSync(1,`destroy ${asyncId} \n`);
  },
}).enable();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('>>>', async_hooks.executionAsyncId());
  }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `console.log` is asynchronous [according to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_printing_in_asynchooks_callbacks)

Comment: Sorry i am new to node js and javascript. Is console.log() is asynchronous in both browser and nodejs? If that so ```let fs = require('fs');
console.log('ended');
fs.writeFileSync(1,`initiated \n`); ``` in this initiated should be printed first. But that's not the case.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: According to your statement, if console.log() is asynchronous then 'initiated' should print first because its synchronous and after that only 'ended' should print. But when i run this program in node runtime, its printing 'ended' first and then only 'initiated' got printed.

Comment: I wonder why the docs and experts tell us console.log is asynchronous but don't explain why we don't have to `await console.log` all over the place.

Comment: @Marc because an "asynchronous resource" as tracked by AsyncHooks is not a promise, and `console.log` still returns undefined.